# The command "make serve" not working

Tags: google-nativeclient

I have installed the pNaCl SDK and have run the command "make serve", as instructed to by the website https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1 into my console, it does not run any server and produces the error message:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\nacl_sdk\nacl_sdk\pepper_33\getting_started>make serv
e
C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_33/tools/make -C part1  all
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, python C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/na
cl_sdk/pepper_33/tools/getos.py, ...) failed.
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper
_33/getting_started/part1'
make[1]: Makefile:27: pipe: No error
C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_33/toolchain/_pnacl/bin/pnac
l-clang++ -o hello_tutorial.bc hello_tutorial.cc -O2 -IC:/Users/USERNAME/Document
s/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_33/include -LC:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl
_sdk/pepper_33/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/
pepper_33/toolchain/_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ -o hello_tutorial.bc hello_tutorial
.cc -O2 -IC:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_33/include -LC:/Us
ers/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_33/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp
-lppapi, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'hello_tutorial.bc' failed
make[1]: *** [hello_tutorial.bc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_
33/getting_started/part1'
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'part1_ALL_TARGET' failed
make: *** [part1_ALL_TARGET] Error 2
```

My username is inserted in the place of USERNAME.
Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like perhaps python is not present in you PATH?  Can you run "python" on the command line?  What does "where python" produce?

I'm somewhere surprised since python is required to install the SDK in the first place.   I've opened a ticket to handle this failure mode:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348139

Comment: I ran "python" and it worked, but ran "where python" and it yielded an  error. I had a look at my PATH and found that if I included C:\Python27 without quotation marks, the Batch file ran correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, had the same issues, what i did was (my setup):

It seems compile script doesn't like paths with spaces, like: "C:\Documents and ...".

1. Make sure python path is at environment variables. "C:\Python27"
2. Put nacl_sdk folder in "C:\stationary".
3. Put custom environment variable NACL_SDK_ROOT to "C:\stationary\nacl_sdk\pepper_34".

There i did immediate variable assignee.

A. "cd C:\stationary\nacl_sdk\pepper_34\getting_started".

B. "set NACL_SDK_ROOT C:\stationary\nacl_sdk\pepper_34".  This must point to the pepper version you want to build against,

C. "make serve".

And that's it! Works, compiled!

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered and solved the same issue. using comment on [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425728/how-to-create-a-ppapi-plugin-for-google-chrome-in-windows). I tried building one of the other examples and they seem to work while the getting started one doesn't.

"You will have a hard time building those ppapi tests. I suggest trying to build one of the examples provided with the SDK. If you really need to build that test (it isn't an example) you will need to use clang (another C/C++ toolchain). However, from a cursory look, those tests aren't actually built in NaCl, nor do they generate a PPAPI plugin. I have never gotten clang working on Windows, but it is apparently possible. See clang.llvm.org/get_started.html for instructions using Visual Studio. I would probably use MinGW instead, but I can't find decent instructions for that. –  DRayX Oct 21 '13 at 16:08 "

Comment: The point is that there is no solution to the problem but only a workaround for the issue that he's experiencing. as such my comment is completely valid and delivers valueable information to the person who answered the question.