# How to develop Chrome/Firefox Plugin (no Extensions ! no npapi!)

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

With the deprecation of NPAPI,  how to develop a Chrome/Firefox plugin insteadof npapi plugin in windows?

i find the below results:

use pppai or nacl/pnacl from bellow link:
   https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/download
   but I find the notes:

Deprecation of the technologies described here has been announced for platforms other than ChromeOS.
 Please visit our migration guide for details.

So how to use it and make chrome/firefox plugin that can be auto-load??

Thanks by advance and sorry for my poor English ( ask me if you don't really understand my answer )

Comment: There is a [chome guide](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration) about the alternatives to NPAPI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a PPAPI plugin for Google Chrome in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425728/how-to-create-a-ppapi-plugin-for-google-chrome-in-windows)

Comment: You are not going to have much luck writing a browser plugin these days. You should consider learning [tag:webassembly] instead.

Comment: hi josh lee , how to use webassembly by C++/C ?